# Unity5 UI Buttons; List with Colors

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

For a Unity project i'm working on, I need to be able to change colors of an object that is currently selected. Anyway I spawn in button prefabs with an script. This script also contains a list with colors. these colors need to be bound to a button. so when i press the red button an object turns red.

```
public GameObject button
public List<Color> ColorOptions;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    foreach(Color color in ColorOptions){
        GameObject newButton = Instantiate(button) as GameObject;
        ButtonController controller = newButton.GetComponent<ButtonController>();
        newButton.GetComponent<Image>().color = color;
        newButton.transform.SetParent(ContentPanel.transform);
        newButton.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
    }
}
```

These buttons get an onclick function to change the color of an object. In the TaskOnClick function, I have put an foreach loop for the color list. In the foreach loop, I give the object the color from the list. Yet the buttons only give the last color in the list. Script for Button

```
public Text Name;
public Button button; // Prefab Button

GameObject floor;
GameObject floorHolder;
ListController colorList;

void Start()
{
    Button btn = button.GetComponent<Button>();
    btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    // Find floorHolder
    floorHolder = GameObject.Find("FloorHolder");
    //Get ListController from grandparent
    colorList = transform.parent.parent.GetComponent<ListController>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    //Get FloorHolders Child Object
    floor = floorHolder.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
}

// Called when Button is Pressed
void TaskOnClick()
{
    //Change Color of the Material 
    foreach(Color color in colorList.ColorOptions){
        floor.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = color;
    }
}
```

So for example, the list contains the colors : Red, Blue, Green, Yellow, Purple. And I have spawned in 5 buttons, if I press 1 of these buttons the object will only turn purple. **So my question is how doe I get these buttons to work with the colors ?** I hope you guys can help me !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `TaskOnClick` function as follows -

```
void TaskOnClick()
{
    //Change Color of the Floor Material to this button's color
    floor.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = button.GetComponent<Image>().color;
}
```

Comment: Note, calling `floor.GetComponent<Renderer>()` and `button.GetComponent<Image>()` inside a method is very inefficient. You should get those component in `Start()`. You also could change the type of `floor` to `Renderer` then when you drag the `GameObject` on to the script it will automaticly pull out only the `Renderer`, you can do the same to the `Image`

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain - is it ever acceptable to use GetComponent<T> to a local variable in methods if we know the method will only be called once? I'm curious of performance

Comment: @Chad If you know it is only going to be called once it would be ok to call it, however IMHO i think it would still be better to do it on Start or via the type of the public variable so that in case you ever change your code so you end up calling the function more than once later down the road in your development you don't need to remember to go back and change the code that called GetComponet<T>